# apache solr with another jvm

Tags: solr, jvm, solrcloud, azul-zing

I use apache solr with Sun's JVM, but for me it's interesting to see how it works with another JVM for examle solr. But I don't know how it possible. I've tried change file solr.in.sh where installed variable SOLR_JAVA_HOME as path to another JVM, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to provide more information of what went wrong with setting teh environment variable and how exactly you started Solr.